# Reset increment after deleting row with Controller in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

i know my question is already asked before. but i still don't get it, bcoz i'm still newbie in laravel. mind to explain in detail, thanks.

So, i want to delete a row with this

View

```
@foreach($items as $item)
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/deleteItem/'.$item->id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button>Delete</button>
</form>
@endforeach
```

Routes

```
Route::post('/deleteItem/{id}', 'ItemController@delete');
```

Controller

```
public function delete($id)
{
    Item::where('id', $id)->delete();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

But after that, when i insert new data the increment doesn't reset.
Example:

```
1 AAA
2 BBB
3 CCC
```

when i delete 2, and insert DDD. increment goes to 4 not to 2.

```
1 AAA
3 CCC
4 DDD
```

How do i make it to like this

```
1 AAA
2 DDD
3 CCC
```

Sorry my question is too long. Mind to explain it to easy way, thank you before.

Comment: This has more to do with `MySQL autoincrement` than Laravel I'd say. Any reason you need it like this?

Comment: Delete has no effect on auto_increment values by design. The purpose of auto_increment is to uniquely identify a row and should not have any significant meaning as far as the app is concerned. It is possible to rebuild id values and auto_increment and you should google mysql reset auto_increment to find approaches for this.

Comment: i have search it in google, but still can't understand. they just resetting the increment column to 0, with sql "ALTER TABLE xxx INCREMENT = 0" or something like that.